# Error "gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name"

Tags: gnupg

I started using [GNU Privacy Guard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard). An error occurs when trying to import a key from any server:

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 908F435E
```

Output:

```
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
```

Comment: you can configure a new keyserver globally https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155433/is-there-a-way-to-globally-set-the-default-keyserver-for-gpg-on-debian

Answer (score 178):

I stumbled upon this today and found the fix at [Maven Central Repository Documentation](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/requirements/gpg/#distributing-your-public-key). The SKS Keyserver Network is being deprecated and probably gone by now. Just use another GPG key server like:

- keyserver.ubuntu.com
- keys.openpgp.org
- pgp.mit.edu

So for example

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key 908F435E
```

Comment: Curious. I am getting the same error as the OP, but this doesn't fix it to me. The error message changes from "No name" to "No data" though.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer That probably indicates the key itself does not exist on the server. To add a key to the keyserver use `gpg --keyserver <key-server> --send-keys <id>`

Comment: That appears to give the same error, regardless of the choice of key server. Hmm, but let me not digress from the topic of this thread too much --- I'll see what I can do.

Comment: If that's not working, e.g. due to a firewall, you could also try it with `hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80`

Answer (score 28):

Try these command one by one. It works for me.

```
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg2 --import
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg2 --import
```

Comment: I don't know if this problem is specific from `rvm`, but this one actually works. Trying hkp://keys.openpgp.org hkp://pgp.mit.edu hkp://keyserver.pgp.com hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com does not work "gpgkeys: key ... can't be retrieved"

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to the options above, from the [RVM security documentation](https://rvm.io/rvm/security),

> If you encounter problem with the key server above, try a different one. Some alternatives are presented below:

- hkp://ipv4.pool.sks-keyservers.net
- hkp://pgp.mit.edu
- hkp://keyserver.pgp.com

The second one worked for me, hkp://pgp.mit.edu

Answer (score 2):

Replace $key with the corresponding $key you want to add.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys $key
```

This works on [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

Answer (score 0):

Please use these commands one by one:

```
curl -sSL https://rvm.io/mpapis.asc | gpg --import -

curl -sSL https://rvm.io/pkuczynski.asc | gpg --import -
```

Or you can refer to the rvm.io.

Comment: This seems to be a plagiarised version of [Waseem Anwar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66217436/error-gpg-keyserver-receive-failed-no-name/68152078#68152078). The sentence content, sentence structure, and command lines are nearly identical.

Comment: Actually i have added this answer before that but someone deleted my answer and don't know why...!

Answer (score -6):

`keys.gnupg.net` is just an alias to `pool.sks-keyservers.net`. You can point directly to this second address and it will work.

Comment: @MiguelConde See one of the other answers.  It seems that these servers do not exist anymore.  You should use other server names.